# VSCode: auto-import does not find modules

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I recently started using vscode for react development and am running into an issue currently.

Given the following little code snippet:

```
export default class foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello World</div>;
    }
}
```

vscode underlines `React` since the name is not defined. When trying to apply a quick fix (alt+enter mapped to `editor.action.quickFix`) vscode recommends the following:

```
import * as React from "../../../Users/daniel/Library/Caches/typescript/2.4/node_modules/@types/react"
```

I have react installed in the current working directory within the `node_modules` folder (installed through npm). Why does vscode not recommend me including react from there and instead wants me to include a typings file?

Expected recommendation:

```
import * as React from "react";
```

My `jsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "checkJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Folder structure:

```
/
   node_modules/
      react/
      ...
   jsconfig.json
   packacke.json
   package-lock.json
   test.js
```

Is there anything wrong with my setup or is there anything else I need to configure before it will work as expected? I have tried reloading the workspace / restarting vscode multiple times so far.

Comment: Having the same problem (not with react, though). Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @ba_ul I eventually went back to using WebStorm for react development as VSCode was giving me troubles on many ends. Didn't take another look at it in the last months, though.